# program exits without error when linking boost library

Tags: c++, boost, linker, arm, shared-libraries

I have a problem with linking boost library into my cross-compiled c++ program.
The code I write is cross-compiled with CodeSourcery under Ubuntu 12.04 for an arm-target (Pandaboard, also Ubuntu 12.04).
Compiling simple test-programs without library works fine, even OpenCV with static libraries works fine.

But here is the problem when linking boost 1.52.0 libraries:

When crosscompiled WITH linking boost libraries (-lboost_thread -lboost_system) the program compiles without errors, but when executing it on target, nothing happens.

**Program finishes without error as if it would have never been executed.**

When crosscompiled with CodeSourcery WITHOUT linking boost libraries: everything works fine on target.
Compiled locally with g++: everything fine as well.

For testing purposes i stripped down my code to the following few lines:
(error even appears when no chrono-function is used. just linking makes the difference)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include<boost/chrono.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    cout << "!!!this test worked!!!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Linker command is (out of eclipse):

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -L/home/xy/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib -o "testARM" ./src/main.o -lpthread -lboost_thread -lboost_system
```

The boost-libraries were cross-compiled with CodeSourcery arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ following [this guide](http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/10/03/cross-compiling-boost-c-libraries-for-arm/).
I copied them all to the target into /usr/lib folder and added /usr/lib to PATH and to  LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I tried remote debugging with eclipse and its the same: starting program.. program terminated with 1.
But nothing happend.

It doesnt even print an error or complain about something missing.
So by now I cant think of anything more I could google that I havent tried...

Could you give me any hints what I could try to fix this?

Many thanks in advance!

---

**Update:**

When running my test program with strace, the log contains following info:

```
    $ vi strace-testARM.log
    22:23:56.511385 execve("./testARM", ["./testARM"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
    22:23:56.512789 brk(0)                  = 0xfae000
    22:23:56.512972 uname({sys="Linux", node="panda", ...}) = 0
    22:23:56.514010 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.514315 mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f9b000
    22:23:56.514498 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.514742 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
    22:23:56.514986 fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=52288, ...}) = 0
    22:23:56.515353 mmap2(NULL, 52288, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f72000
    22:23:56.515536 close(3)                = 0
    22:23:56.515688 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.515902 open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
    22:23:56.516207 read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\5P\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
    22:23:56.516451 lseek(3, 66332, SEEK_SET) = 66332
    22:23:56.516573 read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1400) = 1400
    22:23:56.516787 lseek(3, 65924, SEEK_SET) = 65924
    22:23:56.516909 read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
    22:23:56.517153 fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=100802, ...}) = 0
    22:23:56.517519 mmap2(NULL, 107024, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f57000
    22:23:56.517642 mprotect(0xb6f67000, 28672, PROT_NONE) = 0
    22:23:56.517794 mmap2(0xb6f6e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xf) = 0xb6f6e000
    22:23:56.517977 mmap2(0xb6f70000, 4624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f70000
    22:23:56.518160 close(3)                = 0
    22:23:56.518313 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.518557 open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libboost_thread.so.1.52.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.518832 stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbea34ea8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.519076 open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/libboost_thread.so.1.52.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file 
... [ lots of other directories with file not found ] ...
    22:23:56.545382 stat64("/usr/lib/neon/vfp", 0xbea34ea8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.545565 open("/usr/lib/neon/libboost_thread.so.1.52.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.545748 stat64("/usr/lib/neon", 0xbea34ea8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.545932 open("/usr/lib/vfp/libboost_thread.so.1.52.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.546115 stat64("/usr/lib/vfp", 0xbea34ea8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    22:23:56.546298 open("/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.52.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
    22:23:56.546481 read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\324\331\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
    22:23:56.546755 lseek(3, 121020, SEEK_SET) = 121020
    22:23:56.546878 read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1200) = 1200
    22:23:56.547091 lseek(3, 119052, SEEK_SET) = 119052
    22:23:56.547213 read(3, "A(\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\36\0\0\0\0055TE\0\6\4\10\1\t\1\22\4\24\1\25"..., 41) = 41
    22:23:56.547396 exit_group(1)           = ?
```

---

**Update 2:**

I am compiling my program on an Ubuntu Host, transfer the file onto the Pandaboard and issue the following commands as suggested by @ShaunMarko:

```
`ldd testARM` =>  `not a dynamic executable`

`file testARM` => `testARM: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped`

`file libboost_thread.so.1.52.0` => `libboost_thread.so.1.52.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`
```

Adding `-v -H` to the compiling g++ expression I receive:

```
... /xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/boost/utility/result_of.hpp

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-H' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MF' 'main.d' '-MT' 'main.d' '-o' 'main.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv5te' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-funwind-tables' '-D' '__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MAJ__=2012' '-D' '__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MIN__=9' '-D' '__CS_SOURCERYGXX_REV__=64'
 /xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/as -v -march=armv5te -meabi=5 -o main.o /tmp/cceTwLmn.s
GNU assembler version 2.23.51 (arm-none-linux-gnueabi) using BFD version (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.09-64) 2.23.51.20120829
COMPILER_PATH=/xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/:/xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../libexec/gcc/:/xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/:/xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../lib/gcc/:/xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/:/xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib/:/xy/CodeSourcery/bin/../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-H' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MF' 'main.d' '-MT' 'main.d' '-o' 'main.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv5te' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-funwind-tables' '-D' '__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MAJ__=2012' '-D' '__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MIN__=9' '-D' '__CS_SOURCERYGXX_REV__=64'

**** Build Finished ****
```

(This is the last part, above that there are listed tons of included headers. The xy-Path is where CodeSourcery is installed in my home directory)

Comment: Can you run your program on the target with strace (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Strace)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I posted the strace-log above. Can you derive any useful information from it?

Comment: You can issue "`ldd` testARM" on the target to ensure all the references are resolved.

Comment: When typing "ldd testARM" it says "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: Just to be clear, you are running `ldd testARM` on the ARM target, correct? Also run `file` on your test program and the libboost_thread library in question.

Comment: It may also be useful to use the `-v -H` options with the invocation of g++ to see which headers are being included and which libraries are being linked to the executable.

Comment: Yes, everything is run on target (via SSH terminal). Results please see update 2 in my question. 
Does this help in any way?

Comment: I'm sure you are on the right track with @aauselen below. It seems to be a conflict between hard and soft float ABI. ldd on your binary should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General rule for building ARM applications (in fact it must be true for any platform)

> > You must compile your entire program with the same ABI, and link with a compatible set of libraries.

In your case last item looks like `/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.52.0` and since it is also related to your usage, be sure that `libboost_thread` matches the one on the host that you are cross compiling.

```
22:23:56.546298 open("/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.52.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
22:23:56.546481 read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\324\331\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
22:23:56.546755 lseek(3, 121020, SEEK_SET) = 121020
22:23:56.546878 read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1200) = 1200
22:23:56.547091 lseek(3, 119052, SEEK_SET) = 119052
22:23:56.547213 read(3, "A(\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\36\0\0\0\0055TE\0\6\4\10\1\t\1\22\4\24\1\25"..., 41) = 41
22:23:56.547396 exit_group(1)           = ?
```

With `ARM` systems you can have many variants of a library like different ABIs or VFP/NEON support and getting an off the shelf toolchain might not match what you target by default just because it is for ARM.

**update**

If you check a previous log

```
22:23:56.515902 open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
22:23:56.516207 read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\5P\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
22:23:56.516451 lseek(3, 66332, SEEK_SET) = 66332
22:23:56.516573 read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1400) = 1400
22:23:56.516787 lseek(3, 65924, SEEK_SET) = 65924
22:23:56.516909 read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
```

You see two things, first your system is `hf` from the path. In the read data we also see `7-A`, which probably means ARMv7-A compared to `5TE` which probably means ARMv5TE from your libboost_thread library. You should use readelf from your toolchain to get information about elf files instead of file utility.

I would try to compile boost with `-march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard` and put the resulting binary under `/usr/lib/vfp.

I think reading [vfp stuff](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison) from Debian site can help you greatly and you should make small exercises yourself, instead of dealing with compilation process of boost to understand the situation.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I now did some research on ABI and abihf (which apparently is default for Ubuntu 12.04)
I have now tried to compile the complete boost libraries and afterwards my program with flag `-mfloat-abi=hard`, as well as with `-mfloat-abi=softfp`
Unfortunately nothing changed in both scenarios.

Comment: From what I read so far, one thing I could imagine is that the program mixes up hard- and soft-float libraries on runtime.

Is there a way to execute the program forcing it to search only for desired shared libraries? (e.g. `libstdc++` etc...) There is one in `/usr/lib/` folder and one in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`, I need to say "use thist one"

Comment: After a lot of recompiling and library-copying your suggestion really did it. Compiled boost and my program with `-march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard` and now it works. Thank you so much @auselen.