# error while loading shared libraries on arm Debian

Tags: c++, linux, arm, debian, gracenote

I compiled and ran a program making use of the Gracenote SDK on x64 Arch Linux using cmake/gcc with no problem. Now, when I compile and then run on arm Debian I get the following error:

```
/src/tracker-linux: error while loading shared libraries: libgnsdk_musicid.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have verified that this file exists and is symlinked in /usr/lib, and strace seems to suggest that the file *is* found (see below). What else should I try?

ldd output:

```
libgnsdk_musicid.so => not found
libgnsdk_manager.so => not found
libgnsdk_dsp.so => not found
libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0 (0xb6f37000)
libportaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libportaudio.so.2 (0xb6f0e000)
libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libasound.so.2 (0xb6e70000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6e54000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6da9000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6d3e000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6d1a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6c3c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0xb6c2d000)
libjack.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjack.so.0 (0xb6c0d000)
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f95000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0xb6c02000)
```

strace output:

```
execve("./src/tracker-linux", ["./src/tracker-linux"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x318000
uname({sys="Linux", node="beaglebone", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f5b000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/tls", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0T\222\3\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 821484, SEEK_SET)              = 821484
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 820884, SEEK_SET)              = 820884
read(3, "A,\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\"\0\0\0\0055TE\0\6\4\10\1\t\1\22\4\24\1\25"..., 45) = 45
close(3)                                = 0
stat64("/home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31208, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 31208, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f39000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon", 0xbefa4ee8)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls", 0xbefa4ee8)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon", 0xbefa4ee8)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls", 0xbefa4ee8)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v7l/neon", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v7l/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v7l/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v7l", 0xbefa4ee8)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/neon/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/neon/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/neon/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/neon", 0xbefa4ee8)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/vfp/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/vfp", 0xbefa4ee8)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libgnsdk_musicid.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0T\222\3\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 821484, SEEK_SET)              = 821484
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 820884, SEEK_SET)              = 820884
read(3, "A,\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\"\0\0\0\0055TE\0\6\4\10\1\t\1\22\4\24\1\25"..., 45) = 45
close(3)                                = 0
stat64("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
writev(2, [{"./src/tracker-linux", 19}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"libgnsdk_musicid.so", 19}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"No such file or directory", 25}, {"\n", 1}], 10./src/tracker-linux: error while loading shared libraries: libgnsdk_musicid.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) = 138
exit_group(127)
```

**Edit (add some /usr/lib/ contents):**

Output of `ls -alh /usr/lib/ | grep gnsdk`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  108 Sep  6 12:01 libgnsdk_dsp.so -> /home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/libgnsdk_dsp.so.3.06.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  108 Sep  6 12:01 libgnsdk_dsp.so.3.06.0 -> /home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/libgnsdk_dsp.so.3.06.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  112 Sep  6 12:01 libgnsdk_manager.so -> /home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/libgnsdk_manager.so.3.06.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  112 Sep  6 12:01 libgnsdk_manager.so.3.06.0 -> /home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/libgnsdk_manager.so.3.06.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  112 Sep  6 11:59 libgnsdk_musicid.so -> /home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/libgnsdk_musicid.so.3.06.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  112 Sep  6 11:59 libgnsdk_musicid.so.3.06.0 -> /home/debian/tracker-linux/tracker-linux/gnsdk-3.06.0.1241o-20130927/lib/linux_arm-32/libgnsdk_musicid.so.3.06.0
```

Comment: Been there, seen that. Probably it's a 32-bit library and you're running this on a 64-bit system with no 32-bit runtime installed.

Comment: Did you add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, did you install gracenote, did you run `ldconfig` after?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant armv7l, which is what this is running on, has only 32-bit. The .so file is "ELF 32-bit LSB shared object"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch From strace output, it doesn't appear that /usr/local/lib is being examined (I suppose it's probably not in ld.so.conf). However, I have symlinked the files to /usr/lib/, which *is* being examined, and ran `ldconfig` after, and it made no difference.

Comment: Either this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14498124/1163019) or that lib's loader is missing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234088/execve-file-not-found-when-stracing-the-very-same-file

Answer (score 1):

The error message actually is a bit misleading. This:

```
libgnsdk_musicid.so => not found
libgnsdk_manager.so => not found
libgnsdk_dsp.so => not found
```

should give you a hint. The lib libgnsdk_musicid.so itself depends on other libs which also have to be available in the current search path for libraries.

Comment: No change after symlinking those in /usr/lib and running ldconfig. strace and ldd result in the same output as before.

Comment: what does **ldconfig -v** say about libgnsdk_musicid.so etc ?

Comment: The I too have to ask **(1)** Id /usr/lib in your /etc/ld.so.conf **(2)** do you have a link libgnsdk_musicid-<bla>.so<bla> -> libgnsdk_musicid.so in your /usr/lib (where <bla> might be a version) ?

Comment: I just added /usr/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf and did `ldconfig -v` and the libraries now show up. However, I still get the same errors.

Comment: and ldd doesn't complain anymore about any missing libs ? Also check the new libs with ldd (I always wished for a recursive ldd).

Comment: gimme the output of ldconfig -v | grep musicid

Comment: Pretty sure I saw it in there before, but then I messed with some things and at any rate it no longer shows up in `ldconfig -v`. Added relevant files from /usr/lib/ to my post.

Comment: A bunch of libraries show up with `ldconfig -v` under /usr/lib/, just not the gracenote ones.